# Simple deform > Bend modifier doesn't work as expected

Tags: animation

I thought it would be easy to use the simple deform modifier, just bending a simple flat cube on x - axis. if i try this in the origin, everything works as expected. (left on image)

Unfortunately I want the same deforming a little more far right (right side) on the y - axis....and it didn't work. I tried with empty, with empty moving...ctrl-a ...nothing. it must be pretty easy, but i cannot figure it out...

Here is my blend file to reproduce: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the expected result your object needs to be subdivided first. See more at
 https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html?highlight=simple%20deform%20bend

Comment: thank you very much...i cannot believe i made the same mistake the 10th time ...OMG